# Schedule laravel 5.3 tasks to run every minute in windows

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, laravel-5.3

I'am developing a project in laravel 5.3 where in a particular command that I created prints "Hello".
I want this command to be called after every 1 minute.
I know in linux you can use cron to schedule the tasks but I'am using windows so I used the windows taks to schedule a .bat file to run after every 1 minute,but it doesnt work.

My .bat file looks like this

cd c:\Users\User\Desktop\alerts

C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.exe artisan schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1

The schedule function in the Kernel.php looks like this:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
 {
  $schedule->command('custome:command')->everyMinute();
 }
```

And the actual task that will be called looks like this

```
 public function handle()
{
  echo 'Hello';
}
```

It doesn't give any output. It should automatically print "Hello" after a minute right? But it doesn't. Where is the output shown?

Comment: after the php.exe file should be the complete path artisan of your project.

Comment: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.exe c:\Users\User\Desktop\alerts artisan schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1


Is this what you mean @aldrin27

Comment: why it's not on the xampp folder?

Comment: I'm using wamp server so it should be the wamp path...
Sorry my bad.Thanks.
but can you tell me where can i see the o/p ?

Comment: Please can anyone help me on this need it ASAP!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am going to simplify the process for you.

The content of your .bat file should rather be 
"C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.exe" "c:\Users\User\Desktop\alerts\artisan" "schedule:run"

NB: According to the directories from your question.

Create a task and call this .bat file as an "Action" in the Task Scheduler on your windows.

```
public function handle(){ logger("Hello"); }
```

The logger function will output your message to the default laravel log file "laravel.log" for u to see at the bottom.

Hope it helps others too.